# Как подгружать объекты в EF Core из БД полностью, с вложенными объектами?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Делаю слой DAL с использованием Entity Framework Core. Есть такие модели:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Name", TypeName="nvarchar(50)")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Description", TypeName = "nvarchar(255)")]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    [Column("Price")]
    public int? ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Name", TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

}
```

Сделал репозитории для каждой модели, вот абстрактный класс с общей функциональностью (пишу только интересующий метод):

```
abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected internal ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; }

    public RepositoryBase(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        this.ApplicationContext = context;
    }
    ...

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return this.ApplicationContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
    }
    ...

}
```

И один из репозиториев:

```
class ProductRepository : RepositoryBase<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    public ProductRepository(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Почему, когда я ставлю точку останова на метод FindAll(), вызываю этот метод для модели Product, проверяю что возвращается из метода, и в возвращенных объектах Product в поле Category (и Supplier) стоит null. Как сделать чтобы они тоже загружались из БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод Include:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
{
    return this.ApplicationContext.Set<T>()
        .Include(x => x.Category)
        .Include(x => x.Supplier)
        .AsNoTracking();
}
```

Comment: т.е. мне переназначить этот метод для конкретно этого репозитория? иначе нельзя включать конкретные поля

Comment: P.S. сделал для конкретного репозитория метод с включением через Include и всё хорошо, спасибо.
`public new IEnumerable<Product> FindAll()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContext.Products.Include(x=> x.Category).Include(x=> x.Supplier).AsNoTracking();
        }`